# In CSS, can I add text of a different style before or after other text?

Tags: css

For example, if the following is part of an HTML file:

```
<span>foo</span>
```

can I somehow add " bar" after it in italics with the `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements in CSS so that it would say "foo *bar*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
span:after {
  content: "bar";
  font-style: italic;
}
```

It is however CSS3 and not widely supported (yet). See [4.2. Inserting content into an element: the '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting).

Comment: `:after` was introduced in CSS2 (see meder's link); the version quoted uses double-colon notation which is part of CSS3. In terms of browser support, IE7 and older don't support the pseudo-element, but that does not make it new to CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

```
span:after {
    content:' bar';
    font-style:italic;
}
```

This won't work in IE though and possibly other user-agents, and there's a limit to what you can actually style since its generated.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after

Answer (score 0):

cletus' answer is correct since you said "In CSS", but you can use jQuery here for cross-browser compliance.

```
$('span').append('bar');
```